# Where do I put an Impressum on my client's website

Tags: internet

We are busy building one of our first websites for a client in the European market. My client has asked that we add an Impressum to their site. I have been reading about these, and it seems pretty straight forward. I would however like to make sure that I am doing everything correctly, as this appears to be a legal requirement, meaning any miss-step on my end could prove detrimental to my client.

I had initially thought that this information would be something akin to the metadata for the author of a website, but I am coming to understand that it is actually content that should be displayed on the website. I am thus thinking of placing this on the contact page of the site.

My questions are thus this... Do I understand correctly that:

this is the basic information of the owner of the site (name, address, tax info, etc)
that this information needs to be visible to the end-user
that there is no particular place that this needs to be visible (like on every page in the footer for example)
and, that placing it on the contact page would suffice
I would greatly appreciate any advice that anyone would be able to offer in this regard. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to information (in German) on the website [impressum-recht.de](http://www.impressum-recht.de/impressum-kontakt-angaben.html):

> Die Nutzer sollten auch am besten von jeder einzelnen Seite der Webseite die Anbieterkennzeichnung erreichen können.

> Users should also be able to reach the provider identification from every single page of the website.

The page continues to suggest two options - either directly including the information on each page, or a link to another page containing the info.

However: there appears to be no need for this page to be labelled Impressum -

> als Bezeichnung bieten sich "Impressum" oder "Kontakt" an;

> as a designation "imprint" or "contact" are suitable;

There are some more useful tips about the placement and nature of the page on the linked site, which I encourage you to read (it translates well with [DeepL translation](https://www.deepl.com/)).

Comment: Thank you kindly @Neil. That helps quite a lot!